# How to Get Ajax response from a class function?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a class :-

```
 namespace CodeFiles
 {
 public class GetDetails
 {

      public List<string> AllItems(string value)
      {
            string[] items =  { "hassaan", "samina", "noureen", "hafsa", "wajeeh", "farnaz", "basim", "shahnaz" };
            var lst = new List<string>();
            return (from o in items
                    where o.Contains(value)
                    select o).ToList();
      } 
   }
}
```

All i want to use `AllItem` method from ajax response. But wonder how to apply this.

My ajax call is like :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= txtName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "CodeFiles.GetDetails.cs/AllItems",
                data: "{'value': '" + request.term + "' }",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    response(result.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

I am getting error at `url: "CodeFiles.GetDetails.cs/AllItems"` is causing bug.
How to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

you can not pass class name as url. You have to pass only the url of the ajax response file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a web application right?

If this is the case, make an webform or if this already exist, you only need to create a static method decorate with [WebMethod] then inside the method init the class and call the method AllItems.

Simple example:

On Default.aspx:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Hello(string name)
{
    return name;
}
```

Then in your js:

```
function Hello() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/Hello",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            response(result.d);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('There is a problem processing your request');
        }
    });
}
```